# How to interpolate the current value of a variable in Angular?

Tags: angular, string-interpolation

I have this code in my ts file:

```
currentDate;
get_current_date() {
  this.currentDate = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'en');
}
```

And this in my HTML inside an ngFor directive:

```
<span class="hist-time">
  {{ currentDate }}
</span>
```

How do I get the current value of currentDate so that `currentDate` will display distinct dates and not the same date every time it updates?

Example:

```
2019-12-02 13:06:01
2019-12-02 13:06:13
2019-12-02 13:06:26
2019-12-02 13:06:51
```

and not:

```
2019-12-02 13:06:01
2019-12-02 13:06:01
2019-12-02 13:06:01
2019-12-02 13:06:01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the current time to an array after regular  interval.

Try like this:

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwkra8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

.ts

`import { interval } from "rxjs";`

```
currentTime = [];

constructor() {
   this.currentTime.push(new Date());
   interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
     this.currentTime.push(new Date());        
   });
}
```

.html

```
<p *ngFor="let time of currentTime"> 
     {{ time | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}
</p>
```

Comment: I was thinking of a way where there's no memory required, somewhat like just printing. But this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of @Adrita Sharma post, in case if you don't want to print all values

```
import { interval, Observable, of } from "rxjs";

currentTime: Observable<Date>;

constructor() {
   this.currentTime = of(new Date());
   interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
     this.currentTime = of(new Date());        
   });
}

**HTML**
<p>{{currentTime | async | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}</p>
```